# How to config tomcat 7 to user different css/js files for each app

Tags: tomcat, oracle-apex

I want tomcat to map depending on the url to different css/js/etc folder(each version one folder). I need this for testing different versions of an apex-application. I managed to run 1 application. Now i want to run more. I found something about different host to set up in server.xml. So i put 2 hosts in it.

```
 <Host name="localhost/apex_mcl"  appBase="webapps/apex_mcl"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

  </Host>
```

and

```
 <Host name="localhost/apex_mcl2"  appBase="webapps/apex_mcl2"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

  </Host>
```

Then i edited the web.xml file in ROOT/WEB-INF for "servlet-maping".
The css/js files are in /ROOT/apex_mcl[12]/i

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>apex_mcl</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>debug</param-name>
        <param-value>0</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>listings</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>apex_mcl</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ROOT/apex_mcl/i</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and for apex_mcl2

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>apex_mcl2</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>debug</param-name>
        <param-value>0</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>listings</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>apex_mcl</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ROOT/apex_mcl2/i</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

"i" contains the css/js/etc

if i put my files in /i it is working

Can please someone tell my what i'm missing.

If more information needed just ask.

Mario

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this would be to split the versions into two separate projects and add each to your Tomcat server. After deployment, you can go to `http://localhost:8080/apex_mcl` and `http://localhost:8080/apex_mcl2` and each web page will reference its own css/js.

Comment: could you please be more specific ? like where to put my war files or how to config my web/context/server.xml files.